# What is the reading of the town 北谷?

Tags: word-choice, words, ateji, ryukyuan-languages

What is the reading of the town 北谷? ちゃたん or ほくたに? It is a town in Okinawa. Most Japanese read it as Hokutani or Kitatani. Okinawans say Chatan. Is it a dialect? Could all terms be correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

北谷 is actually not *ateji*, but the usual *kun'yomi* きたたに in Okinawan.

In Okinawan, "[*ki* changes to *ch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okinawan_language)", so one gets

> *kitatani* → *chitatani* > *chitatan* > *chatan*

the first step being *ki* → *chi*, the second dropping the last *i* and the last dropping the first *t* (and contracting *chi a* > *cha*).

As a name of the particular town in Okinawa, it has only one reading in Japanese, namely ちゃたん. However, there are other towns written 北谷 with readings [きたや](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8C%97%E8%B0%B7_(%E8%8D%89%E5%8A%A0%E5%B8%82)) or [きただに](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8C%97%E8%B0%B7%E6%9D%91_(%E6%96%B0%E6%BD%9F%E7%9C%8C)).